# Should I add @throws in PHPDoc to the function using function that throws Exception?

Tags: php, phpdoc

For example consider following code:

```
/**
 * @param array $array
 * @param string $key
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
private function getArrayEntry(& $array, $key)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            'Invalid array of values for location. Missing '.$key.'.'
        );
    }

    return $array[$key];
}

/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return Location
 */
public function createFromArray(array $data)
{
    $this->getArrayEntry($data, 'name');
}
```

Should the second method have @throws in doc bloc too?

How it is used compared to Java where there is 'throws' keyword?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@throws should be only placed in the docBlock of the method where the exception is thrown.
If you put it up the stack it will be redundant and would be a violation of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle!

In java you can choose between @throws and @exception ..see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc)

By the way: You are throwing the wrong type of exception. You should throw a [\OutOfBoundsException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.outofboundsexception.php). Otherwise it's a violation of [POLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).
[\InvalidArgumentException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php) is for an unexpected argument type.

Comment: I generally agree here with Mamuz, though I'd also consider the argument that the doc reader is only going to see the public createFromArray(), not the private getArrayEntry(), so the only way to communicate to the API reader about that thrown exception will be to show it in the public method's docblock.